# Do droids know they inflict pain?

Tags: star-wars, morality

Related to this question about [whether droids *feel* pain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110765/do-droids-feel-pain?noredirect=1#comment263733_110765), I'd like to ask the inverse.

In Star Wars, especially the prequel trilogy we see droids kills, maim or hurt people. In one case even meet this charming, torturous fellow:

[image]

Are there any cases of droids being aware of their actions in harming others? Do any feel remorse for this?

Comment: It's funny how we're so used to Asimov's Three Laws of Robotics that we have to consider how someone could possibly create a robot/droid that could harm humans/sentients.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes droids do purposely inflict pain**

Droids are definitely aware of this fact, multiple times we see R2D2 use his taser for nefarious purposes.

Not really a Force Awakens spoiler but I'll tag it anyway:

> In The Force Awakens we see BB-8 tase Finn to purposely inflict pain.

**Yes droids can feel remorse**

In *Attack of the Clones* 3PO has his head and body separated, his head ends up attached to a battle droid. During this escapade he ends up shooting at a Jedi, after doing so he quickly follows with this line:

> Oh dear, I'm terribly sorry about all this.

He's apologising for his actions as a battle droid this, in my opinion, shows him feeling remorse for his actions.

Comment: “He's apologising for his actions as a battle droid this, in my opinion, shows him feeling remorse” — of course, it’s possible that apologising is merely the correct protocol in that situation.

Answer (score 9):

R2-D2 obviously knows when he’s causing pain since he [uses his taser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiHwW.gif) on retreating Ewoks in *Return of the Jedi*. Warning: Link contains NSFW language!

Note that the Ewok was retreating and R2 had already been freed.

In Legends canon, there were even droids made to kill -- and designed to relish it.